# Chrome Crash Investigation

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, window

Chrome is crashing very very frequently(every 2-3 min). It becomes irresponsive. How can I start investigate why this is crashing so much? It feels to me that certain components of some web pages are triggering the crash. I also checked "C:\Users\irfan\AppData\Local\Google\CrashReports", but this folder is empty.

Some sort of process tacking tool, and keep an eye out for which request is being made just before the crash, or something like that. Any software suggestion?

Im using Windows 7.

Please don't suggest, reinstall chrome. I want to know why this is happening.

Comment: How much memory is being used, and what was the error?

Comment: Mem use 261MB and around 12 tabs were open. There is no error, it becomes irresponsive and shows windows' infamous "Not responding error"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the case; but this happened to me. The profile was corrupt after i got the blue screen of death a couple times.

- You may want to try creating a new user profile: http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=142059

**Some other general troubleshooting ideas**

- Review the Troubleshooting Area: http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/topic.py?hl=en&topic=21605
- Review Known Issues: http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/static.py?page=known_issues.cs *(One of them is the corrupt profile problem listed here)*
- Disable all extensions: http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=113907

Comment: yes, I believe its an IDM issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much good it'll do in this case (Chrome being so architecturally unconventional and all) but [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) the the de-facto process tracking program. Also Resource Monitor is very useful for tracking resources (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd> and then `perfmon /res`).

This is to be expected, though. Chrome handles an inordinate amount of data really quickly. But it sucks in low memory situations because of this. Emptying history and the cache is the cliche answer, but it works. See what happens if you do that once an hour. Does it change anything?