# How can I make Medium work on Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, javascript

I use Medium and Google Chrome (93.0.4577.82) and a few weeks ago Medium simply stopped working properly on Chrome. When I click the buttons in the top navigation bar, the menus don't expand. I have JavaScript turned on, I have disabled all extensions, but nothing helps. I can't even logout from Medium because of this. The only way to logout is by deleting cookies manually. Has anybody experienced similar problems? Any idea what I could do to solve it? I have tried to use developer tools to inspect the console but all I see is this:

```
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not parse content for https://stats.medium.build/lite/sourcemaps/1526.f80f0929.chunk.js.map: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not parse content for https://stats.medium.build/lite/sourcemaps/4388.cd9f554a.js.map: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not parse content for https://stats.medium.build/lite/sourcemaps/manifest.0da17c25.js.map: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not parse content for https://stats.medium.build/lite/sourcemaps/5573.159bf40f.chunk.js.map: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not parse content for https://stats.medium.build/lite/sourcemaps/1034.b7982361.chunk.js.map: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
...
```

Comment: Try using Chrome in incognito mode with all the extensions disabled. Related [1](https://superuser.com/q/300864/152004), [2](https://superuser.com/q/1389855/152004)

Comment: More related: [3](https://superuser.com/q/1523427/152004)

Comment: In incognito mode it works! But in normal mode it doesn't work, even if I disable all extensions =/

Comment: Try deleting the cookies and clearing the cache for Medium. Related [4](https://superuser.com/q/1236345/152004)

Comment: I have deleted the cookies and cleared the cache for Medium, but no luck =/ I played around a bit more and it seems the menu works in other Medium pages, just not in the home page. But that's annoying because that's where I start the navigation, and I can't navigate because the menu doesn't work.

Comment: Try deleting all the cookies and clearing the cache for all sites if that doesn't work you might have to completely reset Chrome.